# Error using a log in random forests Python

Tags: python, random-forest

I'm trying to predict a value. I'm able to predict when I'm using my real target value, it's a number of days, but I try to predict using the log of the value, it gives me an error. I'm using `sklearn` and random forests.

The code:

```
X = final_pressure_df.drop(['y', 'log_y', 'patient_id', 'wound_id'], axis=1)
Y = final_pressure_df['log_y']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, random_state=5)

forest = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', n_estimators=200, max_depth=100, random_state=5)

forest.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

---

The error: `ValueError: Unknown label type: array([[ 3.91202301]`

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need regression, not classification, so use `RandomForestRegressor`.
Classification will not work when the variable being predicted is real-valued (float). And even in your first case, when you are predicting number of days, it still makes more sense to use regression since you are predicting some value, and number of days in not a class/category.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I gone try that!